# Spring DatabaseClient fetch method returns columns values in different order with different column names

Tags: spring, spring-data-r2dbc

When using database client and fetch method which returns Map<String,Any>, the keys seem to be out of order. Am I doing something wrong here?

The code that fetches the map is

```
val result = databaseClient
                .sql(SELECT_ISSUER_METADATA)
                .bind(0, id)
                .fetch()
                .awaitOne()
```

The SELECT_ISSUER_METADATA is `SELECT * FROM ISSUER_METADATA WHERE issuer = ?`
The table contains these columns and values when I ran the example:
[image]

As you can see issuer has value soludcommunity.net while authorization_endpoint has the value soludcommunity.net/authorize.

But when I print the map I got from fetch I get this result:

```
{authorization_endpoint=https://solidcommunity.net, issuer=https://solidcommunity.net/authorize, jwk_uri=https://solidcommunity.net/jwks, registration_endpoint=https://solidcommunity.net/token, token_endpoint=https://solidcommunity.net/register}
```

Am I missing something simple here(I feel like this)?I don't know how to fix this.

I am using MySql R2dbc drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a [bug](https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql/issues/149) in the r2dbc-mysql driver, which has been [fixed](https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql/pull/159) but not yet part of a stable release. So for now, the only option seems to be to [use the build snapshot](https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql#maven), which for maven would look something like:

```xml
    <properties>
        <r2dbc-mysql.version>0.8.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</r2dbc-mysql.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <name>SonaType Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>${r2dbc-mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```